# How to redirect to success / fail pages after php form submission?

Tags: php

I have successfully integrated the following form submission code into my site, and it works great. However I would like to have the code redirect the user to one page if the form submission is successful, and a different page if it fails. How could I adapt the following code to do that? It's really starting to get on my nerves! :-P

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$enquiry = $_POST['enquiry'];
$formcontent=" From: $name \n Phone: $phone \n Message: $enquiry";
$recipient = "email@email.co.uk";
$subject = "Contact Form";
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
echo "Thank You!";
?>
```

EDIT:

Ok I have changed the code to:

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$enquiry = $_POST['enquiry'];
$formcontent=" From: $name \n Phone: $phone \n Message: $enquiry";
$recipient = "email@email.co.uk";
$subject = "Contact Form";
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
if(mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader)){
header("Location: mailer-success.htm");
}else{
header("Location: mailer-fail.htm");
}
exit;
?>
```

This works however it never goes to the fail page. I'm guessing that's because the email is always sent even if fields are empty. I have jquery verification in place (which I have disabled for testing purposes) but that obviously only works for users with javascript enabled. How could I alter the code to only show the success page if the form fields contain data? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Define "successful". If you just want to know if the email was sent, you should replace `die("Error!")` with something more interesting.

Comment: Instead of the final `echo` just use output a location header pointing to either the 'success page' or the 'error page'.

Comment: Just been back through my questions and I had upvoted on 5 out of 8. Of the 3 that I didn't, one was closed and the other 2 I fixed myself using different solutions to those suggested. On both of those I fixed myslef I updated the original post with the solution. Is that ok with you? :-P

Answer (score 7, accepted):

add a redirect to the page:

```
// Test to see if variables are empty:
if(!empty($name) && !empty($email) && !empty($phone) && !empty($enquiry)){
    // Test to see if the mail sends successfully:
    if(mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader)){
        header("Location: success.php");
    }else{
        header("Location: error.php");
    }
}else{
    header("Location: back_to_form.php");
}
```

Comment: Thanks that's exactly what I asked for! However turns out it's not what I needed lol. I have edited the question. If you could take a look I would be grateful

Comment: @Chris I updated the code have a look.

Answer (score 3):

mail function returns true/false when succeeds/fails. So it's rather simple:

```
if (mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader)) {
    header('location: success.php');
} else {
    header('location: fail.php');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add

```
header("Location: successpage.html");
```

to the bottom of your code and remove `echo "Thank you!";`

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the echo and then use a header:

```
header("Location: success.php");
```

If it fails, redirect to error.php

```
header("Location: error.php");
```

If you want to go to the page the form was on, but show an error or success message, do this:

```
header("Location: original.php?status=error")
```

Or change error to success if appropriate, you can then use `$_GET['status']` to determine whether or not the form failed / succeeded.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than send the client a redirect, resulting in another call to your web server, I believe a better way of doing this would be to use a PHP include.

```
if (mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader))
    include 'success.php';
else
    include 'fail.php';
```

Comment: Would this result in the issue of a page refresh resubmitting the POST request?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (failure) {
  header("Location: success.php");
  exit;
} else if (success) {
  echo "thank you";
}
```

Comment: Hmm.."if failure, do a header redirect to success.php" ^^ :) Must be a copy/paste error i think.